# You must supply the parameters: uri, userAgent. when create URI instance CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I'm learning codeigniter 4 and trying to build some test to my controller. I try to test my post method for my controller and create request instance and change to post method like the following CodeIgniter 4 [Documentation : **withRequest**](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/testing/controllers.html#helper-methods) but I got errors like this:

```
There was 1 error:

1) Tests\Support\Controllers\UserControllerTest::testCreateUser
InvalidArgumentException: You must supply the parameters: uri, userAgent.
```

Why the error says uri, userAgent that in documentation just give example uri parameter? And when I look in URI class _construct I just need one argument $uri.

Any help?

Here is my code in controller test :

```
$request = new IncomingRequest(new \Config\App(), new URI("http://localhost:8080/users/create"));

        $criteria = $this->fabricator->make()->toArray();
        $criteria['password'] = 'masdika00';
        $request->setMethod('post');
        $request->setGlobal('post', $criteria);
        
        $postresult = $this->withRequest($request)
                        ->controller(Users::class)
                        ->execute('create');
        
        var_dump($request);
        $this->assertTrue($result->isOK());
        $this->assertTrue($result->see('welcome'));
```

My full  [controller test](https://github.com/masdikaid/e-map-pointer-location-app/blob/master/tests/app/Controller/UserControllerTest.php)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are performing the Feature Testing using Command Line, It will never return the userAgent. So you have to mock the Request as well as the such as Authentication.

Following is the way I have approached Feature Testing.

In the setUp method, I have remapped the URL of the API for Testing. Additionally, I have mocked my Authentication service as well.

```
public function setUp(): void
{
$this->testing_routes = [[ 'post', 'create', 'MyController::create' ]];
$this->authenticationMock = $this->getMockBuilder('Authentication')
        ->getMock();
}
```

Then when testing the API in the method I do as following:

```
public function test_authenticated_user_can_create_entry(){

        $this->authPolicy->method('checkAuth')->willReturn(true);
        $result = $this->withRoutes($this->testing_routes)->post('create', $fabricated_array);
        //assert
    }
```

Here $this->withRoutes returns the mock of the URI routing which is provided by CI4. There might be a better implementation as well since I am currently learning Unit Testing as well.

Reference: https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/testing/feature.html

Comment: thanks for your reply but in my current test i use Feature Test like in HTTP testing documentation instead of Controller testing

Comment: I think you missed the first point. You cannot test IncomingRequest class directly. In the documentation they haven't used IncomingRequest. You have to mock that request and CI4 does that for you when you extend the Test class with CI4s own FeatureTesting class.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer by luck.

- [User Agent syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent)
- [User Agent string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent/Firefox)

```php
<?php

// incorrect
// $request = new IncomingRequest(new \Config\App(), new URI("http://localhost:8080/users/create"));

/**
 * Syntax
 * @see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent
 *
 * user agent strings
 * @see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent/Firefox
 */
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X x.y; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0';
$request = new IncomingRequest(new \Config\App(), new URI("http://localhost:8080/users/create"), 'php://input', new \CodeIgniter\HTTP\UserAgent());

// deprecated
// $request->setMethod('post');

$request->setGlobal('post', ['your-parameter-a' => 'parameter-value-of-a']);

// your code...
```

When you `var_dump`  `$this->request->getPost()` inside your controller, the expected outcome is:

```
array(3) {
  'your-parameter-a' =>
  string(20) "parameter-value-of-a"
}
```